# Cutting a Board and Need Help

Tags: geometry

[image]

I am trying to cut a board and I know two of the dimensions, but I am struggling to calculate the other two dimensions.  I know I want to of the sides to be 14", but what length should the A and B dimensions be?

Comment: Not enough information. How long is the side between the two 14-inches? What's its angle?

Comment: @Yanko Circular logic.

Comment: The side between the two 14" is 14" also.  Not sure of the angle.

Comment: How about you take it as 45°?

Comment: 45 would be perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra information in the comments – the oblique side is $14$ inches and at $45^\circ$ – means that the size of the cut corner is $\frac{14}{\sqrt2}=9.8995$ inches in each dimension, so $A=B=9.8995+14=23.8995$ inches.

Comment: Thanks!  Very helpful.

Comment: @JeffSmith You can accept my answer by clicking the tick below the zero to the left of it. (It will turn green.)